# Fetch monthly high and low of stocks from Yahoo finance

Tags: yahoo-api

I use the following Python code to fetch the high of a stock in a particular month from Yahoo finance:

```
data = yf.download("APPL", start=start_date, end=end_date, interval="1mo")
monthly_high = data['High']
```

But this gives a table, and not the single float value of the stock monthly high. How do I extract only the value and not other fields (like date, name etc.)?

Comment: What does the table look like that you're getting? What columns are there?